# ProgressIndicator is not defined ngCordova.js

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

ReferenceError: ProgressIndicator is not defined.

Shows this error in ngCordova

```
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaProgress.showSuccess(true, "Success!");

    $timeout(function() {
      $cordovaProgress.hide();
    }, 2000);
  });
```

code sample is written like this. where it calls $cordovaProgress.

can anyone help with solution ?

Comment: found answer: that code will work only on mobile device.

Comment: will please post your answer here

Answer (score 0):

You didnt inject the plugin. Inject through the controller of the respective class. :)